# Is there a reason why I am getting no match for operator>>?

Tags: c++

I am working on overloading operators for polynomials. I am working on the >> operator but when i compile my code I am getting an error. It tells me that there is no match for operator>>. I believe that it has to do with the p1.degree that I am using in my code but I am not sure.

I am following an example from my book for operator overloading. When I overloaded the << operator p1.degree worked. Now I am at a stand still.

The class

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
int degree;     // Degree of the poly nomial
int coef[9];        // Array of coefficients

public: 
Polynomial();   // Cunstructor
void get_poly();
void display_poly();
void Add_2_Polynomials(Polynomial, Polynomial);

Polynomial operator + (const Polynomial &); // overloaded + operator
Polynomial operator - (const Polynomial &); // overloaded - operator
Polynomial operator * (const Polynomial &); // overloaded * operator
//friends
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, const Polynomial &);    // Overloaded << operator
friend istream &operator >> (istream &, const Polynomial &);    // Overloaded >> operator


};
```

overloaded >> operator

```
istream &operator >> (istream &strm, const Polynomial &p1)
{
cout << "Enter degree of polynomial: ";
strm >> p1.degree;

cout << "Enter the " << p1.degree+1 << "coeficients: ";

for (int i = p1.degree; i >=0; i--)
    strm >> p1.coef[i];
}
```

I am expecting the code to compile so that i can use the >> get my polynomial information.

Comment: Yepp - mistake. For input, you shouldn't make the 2nd argument of `operator>>` `const Polynomial &p1` but `Polynomial &p1`. How do you want to store result into a const reference? ;-)

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to return `strm` from `operator >>` since it is declared to do so.

Comment: @Diodacus not just a good idea its absolutely required otherwise your program will have undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Make `p1` non-const so you can modify the values within:

```
istream &operator >> (istream &strm, Polynomial &p1)
```

Do the same in the declaration:

```
friend istream &operator >> (istream &, Polynomial &);
```

At the end of `istream &operator >>`, return a reference to the stream:

```
return strm;
```

---

On a side note (it's probably just the example provided), there are unimplemented functions. The code won't link with the unimplemented `Polynomial()`constructor, you can remove the declaration or change it to `Polynomial(){}`.

Comment: You don't have to make `degree` and `coef` variables public - friend function is capable to access them anyway (this is why friendship is for).

Comment: @Diodacus good point, there must be something else wrong too then, because it's not compiling for me with `private`. Actually, that operator implementation isn't any of those signatures given, it's not in a class.

Comment: Add curly brackets after the Polynomial(); constructor. Ie Polynomial(){};. That should make it compile. (Sorry using a phone no backticks)

Comment: @Onyambu good suggestion, I added it to the post

Comment: @Blaze you probably need to remove the `const` in the `friend` declaration so it matches the definition: https://godbolt.org/z/JxwqRu

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, that was the problem. Now it works, thank you.